# How to make a loop in Jquery continue if undefined

Tags: jquery

I have a problem, I have made a script that runs through all images and takes the href of the image and puts it to each buy button under the image. Every image has a buy button underneedth.

But when there is an image without a link the script stops and does not continue to the end.

How could I make it continue till the end?

Found somewhere that `return non-false;` is like continue, but did not work.

Not allowed to put markup sorry.

```
$('.productImg a').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href').indexOf("sometext")> 0 && $(this).attr('href').indexOf("sometext") != 'undefined'){
       $(this).parents(".item").find(".BuyLink a").attr('href',$(this).attr('href'));
    }
    else if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf("sometext") == 'undefined') {
        return non-false;
    }
});
```

Comment: return true for continue and return false for break;

Comment: There is no value "non-false".  If you return false it breaks, if you return anything else it does not.  So I suspect the page you found was saying "return anything which is not false".  You could return "foo" if you want.  But `return true` is the best advice.  Your code is creating an error because your are returning an undefined variable I suspect.

Comment: `indexOf(...)` will never, ever return the string `undefined`. If the string  is not found it returns `-1`.

Comment: even, in comparison, if undefined is not string then comparison is wrong, either !== 'undefined' or != undefiend

Comment: oops you are right @lonesomeday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.productImg a').each(function(){
    if (!$(this).attr('href')) // <--- This checks if the image has a link
        return;

    if($(this).attr('href').indexOf("sometext")> 0 && $(this).attr('href').indexOf("sometext") != 'undefined'){
       $(this).parents(".item").find(".BuyLink a").attr('href',$(this).attr('href'));
    }
});
```

Comment: That was clean bro, thanks. It checks in the beginning if there is not a link and if it doesnt continues to the next one?

Comment: Sure, if the current element doesn't have `href` attribute it will continue the loop.